# ¿Por que no puedo comparar las matrices dentro del if?

Tags: java, matrices

¿Como puedo comparar las matrices dentro del if?, cuando intento entra al if no me deja comparar las matrices, he intentado con el metodo compareTo, menor que nada no funciona.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length - i - 1; j++) {
                        if (datosParticipantes[j][0] < datosParticipantes[j+1][0]) {
                            // Intercambia 2 filas de la matriz.
                            string[] aux2 = datosParticipantes[j];
                            datosParticipantes[j] = datosParticipantes[j+1];
                            datosParticipantes[j+1] = aux2;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println(datosParticipantes[i][j]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: "No funciona" es una mala descripción del problema. Qué error sale? Qué debería pasar y qué está pasando en su lugar? Con qué datos probaste? Por favor, ve a [edit] la pregunta y añade esta información.

Comment: Nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask], continuamente realizas preguntas pero no tienen la información necesaria. Comentas "he intentado con el metodo compareTo", agrega como trataste de realizarlo .  Como deseas compararlas en base a que?, saludos.